# Should I do yoga to avoid upper and lower back injuries?

Tags: yoga, back-pain

I do regular body weight exercises like push-up (25reps,3 sets), chin-ups (10reps,3 sets), Inverted Rows (15reps, 3sets), Squats (20reps, 3sets), Lunges (15reps, 3 sets), Chair Dips (10reps, 3sets), some abs exercises and cardio workouts. Recently I am feeling ache in my upper-back (basically Shoulder Blade) region. Sometime I feel pain in the shoulder blade region when try to move my head or take a deep breath. I tried to take rest for 2-3 days which helps to reduce the pain but after 8-10 days regular exercises the pain comes back again. May be the pain is due to some injuries which are not healing and pressure during body weight exercises increasing it or may be the muscles of that region is too weak. Please provide some guidance so that I get relief from the pain maintaining the strength and stamina of the body. Does practicing yoga helps to get relief from the pain?

N.B. - I have neck spondylitis.

Comment: We're not doctors and can't diagnose problems over the internet, go see a medical professional blah blah blah (that's the standard PF:SE disclaimer). Speaking from a purely non-medical professional point of view, I don't see how yoga would help with the pain you're describing. It really would be something you should think about going to see a physical therapist about (note: don't go to a doctor, they'll just tell you to rest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment you received above is the right answer : go consult a physical therapist.

However, go to him with the proper amount of information and previous medical/sport history. 
You say you started to feel this ache "recently". What did you change ? Did you start doing exercises you are not used to ? Increase the repetitions ? What else ? Or did you just start exercising ? Obviously, something has changed and is the cause of your pain.

Since it it does not seem to be an acute pain (i.e. a muscle tear or something like that) it probably means you are doing something wrong i.e. you are not moving correctly in the exercises you are doing and you start irritating your structures. Moving correctly means moving with the right technique and using the right muscles taking into account your own anatomy.

Resting is usually not the way to go except for acute pain. Obviously while you rest, your structures will heal but as soon as you resume exercising, you will again make the same mistakes and the pain will come back. Understand your movement problem (with the help of a physical therapist), keep training around the pain/injury to increase bloodflow and recovery and eventually resume normal training with proper movement.

Answer (score 0):

Definately yoga helps to relief from upper and lower back injuries, but you need to stop those body weight exercises which is the cause and increasing your upper or lower back pain. However, you can start doing yoga along with body weight exercise. Do some research over the internet and proceed accordingly.

Comment: So, stop doing bodyweight exercise and do yoga and bodyweight exercise? Isn't yoga essentially bodyweight exercise (as in, exercise where you're using your bodyweight for resistance? How is yoga supposed to help with the pain?